# Problem setting width in dynamically created textbox in vb.net

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I use these lines to dynamically create buttons and text boxes.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim newButton = New Button()
        newButton.Text = i
        newButton.ID = i
        newButton.CommandName = i       
        newButton.Style.Add("width", "20%")
        newButton.Style.Add("height", "100%")
        Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton)
    Next

For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim newtext = New TextBox()
        newtext.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine
        newtext.Style.Add("width", "20%")
        newtext.Style.Add("height", "100%")
        Panel2.Controls.Add(newtext)                
    Next
```

While the buttons fit the page width correctly, text boxes leave a space to the right.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnIfb.jpg) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZgZb.jpg)

I've tried assigning a class instead of width, but it doesn't work.

"min-width" also doesn't work.

How to set the text boxes to fit the page width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved setting textbox border-width and padding to zero pixels.

```
newtext.Style.Add("border-width", "0px")
newtext.Style.Add("padding", "0px")
```